# How to align author blocks when using IEEEtran document class

Tags: ieeetran

The second line is not properly aligned when I use the script below:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\title{TITLE}
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{author 1}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of Computer Engineering} \\
\textit{A University}\\
City, Country \\
e-mail}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{author 2}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of Electrical and Electronics Engineering} \\
\textit{A University}\\
City, Country \\
e-mail}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{author 3}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of Computer Engineering} \\
\textit{A University}\\
City, Country \\
e-mail}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{author 4}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of Computer Engineering} \\
\textit{A University}\\
City, Country \\
e-mail}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{author 5}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of Computer Engineering} \\
\textit{A University}\\
City, Country \\
e-mail}
\and
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The alignment looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: please make your code snippet compilable (as complete small document)

Comment: @Zarko I modified the code snippet as you wished.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[in documentation for the package](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) `IEEEtran` you can find on the page 5:

> If there are more than three authors and/or the text is too wide to
>   fit across the page, use an alternate long format:
>
> ```
> \author{
> \IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
> Homer Simpson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
> James Kirk\IEEEauthorrefmark{3},
> Montgomery Scott\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and
> Eldon Tyrell\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
> \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
> Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta, Georgia 30 332--0250\\
> Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
> \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Twentieth Century Fox, Springfield, USA\\
> Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
> \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Starfleet Aca
> demy, San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
> Telephone: (800) 555--1212, Fax: (888) 555--1212}
> \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Tyrell Inc.,
> 123 Replicant Street, Los Angeles, California 90210
> --4321}}
> ```

which gives:

[image]

this means that you should rewrite your `author` field on the way as is shown above.